# Grails: Dynamically inject service in domain class

Tags: grails, groovy, dependency-injection, service

I need to inject a service based on domain property, so far I came up with the following:

```
ApplicationHolder.application.getServiceClass("package.${property}Service").clazz
```

but loading it this way doesn't inject it's dependent services. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

New instances will bypass Spring's dependency management; you need to get the configured singleton bean from the application context. Use this instead:

```
def service = ApplicationHolder.application.getMainContext().getBean("${property}Service")
```

That assumes that 'property' is the partial bean name for a service, i.e. for FooBarService, the property would have to be 'fooBar'. If it's 'FooBar' then you can use GrailsNameUtils.getPropertyName() to fix it:

```
import grails.util.GrailsNameUtils

String beanName = GrailsNameUtils.getPropertyName(property) + 'Service'
def service = ApplicationHolder.application.getMainContext().getBean(beanName)
```

Comment: Yay, it works. I tried getBean method, but was passing 'FooBar' to it :)

Comment: The above wasn't working for me until I replaced `.getMainContext.` with `.getMainContext().`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it after seeing that your edit was incorrectly rejected

Answer (score 3):

IMHO domain classes shouldn't contain logic at all (apart form the validators).

In my projects I normally create a service for each domain class (e.g. **UserService** for class **User**) and I stick all the logic in there, even small bits in pieces that would normally be in the domain class.

I think a lot of programmers coming from Java/C++ world tend to find this ugly, but it suits better the Grails architecture.

Comment: It's true that Grails domain classes aren't really suited for logic, but this is a shame because I have to agree with Fowler on this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_Domain_Model

Comment: Indeed, Eric Evans probably felt a disturbance in the force, when someone says "domain classes shouldn't contain logic at all ".  That's sounds like a Domain object anti-pattern and is completely counter to Domain-driven Design.

Comment: In my case, i'd like to set an index TTL based on grails environment.  What's a better pattern for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Services aren't injected into domain objects.  If your domain object needs something for a particular use case, let the service that owns that use case invoke the other service on the domain object's behalf.

Comment: Any Spring bean can be injected into domain classes just like in controllers, i.e. "def fooService". The common use case for this is to call a service in a custom validator.

Comment: Can be; I just disagree that it should be.  A validator is different from a domain object like an Account or a Person.  It's a completely different use case.