# issue with injecting grails service in domain class

Tags: grails, service, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject 'GraauditService' into grails 'User' domain class. 
I am using grails 1.3.7
I have tried direct injection method as I do in controllers 
import com.gra.audit.GraauditService

```
class User {
def graauditService // or even GraauditService graauditService with graauditService as transient
.......
```

the above does not work.  `graauditService`  is always coming up as null

I also tried to inject through `ApplicationHolder` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814139/grails-dynamically-inject-service-in-domain-class)

But looks like ApplicationHolder is deprecated now

How can I use the service in the domain class?

Comment: You're not supposed to do this, traditional web architectures resemble the [microkernel pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) where the Domain is the kernel. Long story short: domain classes deal with "business domain" logic, and sometimes domain-oriented services act as facades providing common actions involving the domain. That's why Grails won't inject services on domain classes, it's not ok to invoke them from there.
Whatever you're trying to do, it's probably better suited for being done in the service layer. Could you please expand on what you need to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to add auditlog entries on various event for this domain class like save, delete, load..etc

Comment: @Esteban it is simply not true that Grails won't inject services into Grails doman classes. In my application I successfully inject `springSecurityService` into my domain class so I can encode user's passwords before saving them. I disagree with your assertion that injecting services into domain classes is always a bad practice

Comment: I believe your argument is not very strong, why would you do that? I'm not it for anemic domain classes, but injecting services into domain classes generates a dependency loop, which is not usually a good architectural decision. @pri_dev: here's how one could elegantly implement an event-based audit interceptor in Grails: [Inside Hibernate Events](http://hartsock.blogspot.com/2008/04/inside-hibernate-events-and-audit.html).  
In my opinion, plain passwords shouldn't be handled by a server anyway. Why wouldn't you encode passwords in the client or as soon as they reached the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Grails 1.3.7, the solution is to inject it through the `ApplicationHolder`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814139/grails-dynamically-inject-service-in-domain-class) by Burt Beckwith.

The above solutions may work for Grails 2.0, but not for 1.3.7 or earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me

```
class User {

    def springSecurityService
    static transients = ['springSecurityService']
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was looking at Grails 2.0.  Forgot they changed it from 1.3.7.

Comment: It works for me when I get the service from the ApplicationHolder. Thats good for now..

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting it using the transient keyword:

```
class User {
   transient graauditService 
}
```

Comment: It still comes up as null, it comes up non null when I use the ApplicationHolder method but, its not calling the method in the service?

Comment: Does this service inject into controllers ok?  What is the actual Class name of this service?

Comment: the slass name is GraauditService and the following declaration in the controller GraauditService graauditService works fine.